# "That is me" vs "that am I"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, be

For example when pointing to a picture: Is "that am I" grammatical at all? Did it use to be grammatical?

Comment: "That am I" is not (and has never been) grammatical. "That is me" (or "That's me") is correct.

Comment: *That is I* is correct, although *That is me* is idiomatic.

Comment: "It's a me, Mario!"

Comment: There is a style of speech (sometimes referred to as *Yoda speak*) where (among other things) the order of the subject and object are reversed around a tense of the verb *to be*.  In this style the sentence is considered to "I am that".  I'm not sure whether this style is considered "formal" or, rather, "poetic", however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was good enough for Shakespeare (*Much Ado About Nothing*, Act IV, Scene 2)

> Sexton: Which be the malefactors?
> Dogberry: Marry, **that am I** and my partner.

But bear in mind that Dogberry is a comic figure, given to malapropisms and unintentional word play.

The phrasing also shows up in so-called "esoteric astrology", in which we are supposed to find that ["the traditional meanings of the signs, planets and houses may also be utilised in a soul-centred delineation."](http://www.aplaceinspace.net/Pages/CandyJourneyoftheSoul.html) The "delineation" for Leo is

> I am That and **That am I**.

Some attribute the phrasing to Alice Bailey, one time theosophist and writer on alternate spirituality, who wrote books that she said were dictated to her telepathically by a guru named Djwhal Khul whom she called "The Tibetan". I can't confirm this. The attribution, that is.

At least Dogberry was supposed to be ridiculous.

A little time spent in the google finds the following song in a short story "A Perfect Cure" in [*Chambers's Journal, Volume 75*](https://books.google.com/books?id=60xTAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA48&lpg=RA1-PA48&dq=%22that%20am%20i%22&source=bl&ots=La-Dm_VP4t&sig=4YLhr6ViDyyigh4s2tl3MODcmlc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4poHr69vPAhUIMz4KHY-0DWU4ChDoAQhEMAg#v=onepage&q=%22that%20am%20i%22&f=false) (1898):

> Lo! if a woman cross my path,
> Straightway she reels beneath my wrath;
> over her body I go by.
> All that fierce Fire is — **that am I**!
>
> Those who have fire for enemy,
> No happy ending theirs shall be;
> Bare to the winds their bones shall lie.
> All htat fierce Fire is — **that am I**!

Notice that verb and subject have been inverted for emphasis. In ordinary and modern parlance, the Sexton would ask, "Are you guilty?" and Dogberry would respond, "That I am".  The inverted phrasing is stilted and archaic, useful I suppose, for effect. Other parallel uses -- *thus am I*, *here am I*, and *there am I* -- have more currency.